# Error when enrolling arduino device type

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I followed this tutorial from the WSO2 IoT Server documentation in order to enroll an arduino device type : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Arduino.

I get an error when I execute this line : "mvn clean install -f device-plugins-deployer.xml"

```
[ERROR] P2 publisher return code was 13
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: P2 publisher return code was 13
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.generateRepository(RepositoryGenMojo.java:255)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.createRepo(RepositoryGenMojo.java:204)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.execute(RepositoryGenMojo.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

The log file give me this :

```
!SESSION 2017-11-27 10:19:29.039 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_152
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -source /home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/tmp.1511774368842/featureExtract -metadataRepository file:/home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/p2-repo -metadataRepositoryName analytics-devicetype-feature-installation -artifactRepository file:/home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/p2-repo -artifactRepositoryName analytics-devicetype-feature-installation -publishArtifacts -publishArtifactRepository -compress -append
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -source /home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/tmp.1511774368842/featureExtract -metadataRepository file:/home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/p2-repo -metadataRepositoryName analytics-devicetype-feature-installation -artifactRepository file:/home/bacor/workspace/wso2iot-3.1.0-update1/wso2/analytics/samples/device-plugins/target/p2-repo -artifactRepositoryName analytics-devicetype-feature-installation -publishArtifacts -publishArtifactRepository -compress -append

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-27 10:19:29.312
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

It seems there's something missing in the "config.ini" file. I've searched this file into my WSO2 repository and I have got 6 "config.ini" files located at "wso2/component/[component_name]/configuration/".

My question is what "config.ini" file should I modify and what should I modify in order in order to make it work ?

I tried to add this line "org.eclipse.core.runtime@start" to the osgi.bundle line in each "config.ini" but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the IoTS version you are trying? I have tried this with 3.1.0 GA release and it is working fine.

Comment: Hi, I also tried with the 3.1.0 release. I got it from this link : https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/tag/v3.1.0-update1

Comment: Hi I have tried this with IoTS 3.1.0 Update 7 and it was worked for me. You can download update 7 from: https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/tag/v3.1.0-update7

Comment: `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: P2 publisher return code was 13` this issue is common when using an incompatible maven version. What is the maven version you are using? try using maven v3.x

Comment: It should be this, I am running Apache Maven 3.3.9, I'll try with the 3.5.2 version